Unbound local-zone use Wildcard for any Subdomain
The idea is to configure unbound so that it resolves only mydomain.tld, but not any of its subdomains. For example www.mydomain.tld should not be resolved.
Have tried the following, but without success as it resolves www.mydomain.tld then:
local-zone: . always_nxdomain
local-zone: mydomain.tld transparent

This either didn't work:
local-zone: . always_nxdomain
local-zone: mydomain.tld transparent
local-zone: *.mydomain.tld always_nxdomain

The only way seems to be this:
local-zone: . always_nxdomain
local-zone: mydomain.tld transparent
local-zone: www.mydomain.tld always_nxdomain

But this way means to list all conceivable subdomains, which is not a solution if you want to prevent resolving subdomains by default.
Is it possible to configure unbound so that it resolves mydomain.tld, but none of its subdomains, without having to list each explicitly?
